# Janrain and Tomcat authentication

Tags: authentication, tomcat, janrain

I have a login webpage in which i authenticate the users.
Username and Password are stored in MySQL table and the authentication is done by using Apache Tomcat 6.0 and j_security_check option.

I wish to add my website the possibility to also ogin with Janrain widget.
I use Janrain API to do so and in the relevant servlet i catch the Janrain response and parse the user data.

My question is how do i tell Tomcat, from this point, that the user is already authenticated and that now we should redirect him to the main webpage.

Thanks in advance,
Asaf

Answer (score 0):

Asaf --

It's easiest to think of Engage as being the authentication piece, but you would need to handle the authorization piece. Essentially, you'll need to authorize the user on your end as you would someone who has signed in with traditional login.